# How to run a function periodically in .bashrc script file?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I wanted to run a particular function in .bashrc script file ( which actually does a job of removing a docker exited containers in the background)

I already looked into cron but it is not useful for me please suggest any other methods to do it.

I also tried writing a while loop along with sleep which is not the efficient method as we start it every time and stop it.

Comment: What about writing a service?

Comment: »*looked into cron but it is not useful for me*« Care to explain why? Also, are you using linux or git-bash on windows – it's not clear since both tags are there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sadly your question is very broad. Could you inform us why the usage of `cron` is not possible, and what your particular goals are? Also show us what you tried (the cron and the while-loop) and tell us why these solutions did not work for you.

Comment: @Jakkarohith : Why does it have to be a function (which limits the possibilities), and can't be a script on its own? In what way is `sleep` inefficient? In any case, if you want to start and stop it dynamically, a service would, as danlor suggested, probably be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

First choice is cron, but you can also use *at*.

Here is a little example. The script is started once per minute and loggt each run into logfile.dat

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "bash $0" | at now +1 minutes -M
date >> /tmp/logfile.dat
```

With *atq* you can see witch jobs waiting for next run an with *atrm* you can stop the cycle.

==> `man at`

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily consider this a great idea either, but to answer the question you asked...

Here's a simple template you should be able to adapt.

```
chime() { 
  local chimeDelay=10             # seconds, adjust to your needs
  echo "bong!"; date;             # code that Does The Thing
  sleep $chimeDelay && chime &    # snooze and Do The Thing again
} >/tmp/chimelog 2>/tmp/chime.err # logs, not your console
```

Once you execute this it should keep spawning as long as you are logged in, but ought to collapse on a HUP, which I assume is what you wanted. If you just wanted a `cron` substitute, then write and run it as a simplistic daemon with a HUP trap, but you probably should add locks to keep multiple instances from running, etc.